# CSS module not working on react component

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, css-loader, react-css-modules

I am trying to use css module in my reactjs application. I have added the loader in `webpack.config` file.

```
 {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'

            },
```

But when I import a css file in my application and try to use it for `classNames` like `{styles.example}` then it does not link to .example in my css file.

This is how I am doing it:

```
import styles from './TestPage.css'

<div className={styles.example}></div>
```

This is not working.

Components are not styled. I am not getting any error in console though. How can I solve it?

Comment: try changing style to style-loader

Comment: It Didn't work.

Comment: maybe your loader is not appropriate.test after changing your loader

Comment: try this { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'}

Comment: This won't activate the module mode of css loader. This is just a css loader.

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: This is just a css loader, you can not do styles.example.
This will just import your stylesheet and make it usable for the app.

Comment: No error. The components are just not getting the styles

Comment: @user3408151 how can I use styles.example then?

Comment: @ApurvG what is your end goal here?
Do you just want to apply styles to your app or do you specifically want to use styles.example only?

Comment: @user3408151 I have a css file. I want this css file to be used for one specific component. So I was trying to make a local css file for  this component. That was my end goal. And I can do it with css modules. right?

Comment: If your TestPage.css just contains the css for one component, then importing it in that component like you did should style your div.

Just give your div the correct className

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145890/discussion-between-apurvg-and-user3408151).

Answer (score 6):

You need to ***Rename*** the file

from **filename.css**  to  **filename.module.css**

Usage:

*login.module.css*

```
.login {
    background-color: red;
}
```

*Login.js*

```
import styles from './login.module.css';

const login = (props) => {
    return (
            <div className={styles.login} >
                Login Card
            </div>
    )

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be because of old react-scripts version.Just update your react-scripts version more than 2.0.3.

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact react-scripts@2.0.3
```